# HTML5 validations are not working in backbone.js onclick routing to another view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, backbone.js

I am working on backbone.js. Actually i developed some forms in html5.
Please see below code

```
<form>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="nickname"  required />
<label for="name">email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email"  required />
<button id="login" class="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and onclick submit button i am routing to some other view but my html5 validations are not working in this. It simply skips html5 form validations
Please see below backbone code :

```
events:{      
    "click .submit":"submit",

},
submit: function( event )
{       
    app.navigate('abc', true);      
    window.history.back();
    }
```

Till now when add `$Backbone.Validation.bind(this);` in submit function then html5 validations are working but routing to another view is not working.Actually I don't want to create model in backbone and give validation model. I want to use html5 validations only.
can you please help me on this?

can somebody tell  me `app.navigate` works on `submit` in backbone?

Answer (score 1):

They work as they should. You have to listen to submit event instead of click.

```
events : {      
  'submit' : 'submit'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/csr8S/

Comment: ......i agree with you that when i change click to submit then html5 validations are working but routing doesn't work....can you please help?

Comment: You navigate to `abc` and then immediately go back with `window.history.back();`. This should be your problem.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer was correct the best way to say thanks is to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

seems like backbone ignores the html5 response, 
but looks correct to me because you are not catching any error's but directly routing it through.

Comment: @notsure...exactly...i couldnt understand why backbone ignores html5 response/\

Comment: To me it seems that you are listening to the wrong event. by catching the click you are directly routing your user interaction to some other destination. instead you should let the html5 validator do its job and only trigger your custom code after this process is done by waiting for the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You can call click event without preventDefault:

```
  events: {
    "click input[type='submit']": "save_all" 
  },
```

and

```
  save_all: function(event){
    if(!$("div.panel-instance-form form")[0].checkValidity()){
      return true;
    }else{
      event.preventDefault();
          this.form_to_model();
          this.model.save();   
          ... 
          return true;
        }
  },
```